# Java Case insensitive when including a dot

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble with case-insensitive pattern in Java.

According to [online tools](http://regex101.com/) and to my understanding, the string:

`"1-800 flowers.com, CO."`

Should matches the regex pattern:

`"(\s|^)((?i)\Q1-800 FLOWERS.COM, CO.\E)(\s|$)"`

But, when building this pattern in Java, it doesn't match...

I think the problem has to do with case sensitivity, because the following string does match (I only changed ".com" to ".COM"):

`"1-800 flowers.COM, CO."`

This is how I've built it in Java:

```
String phraseToReplace="1-800 flowers.com, CO.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)((?i)" + Pattern.quote(phraseToReplace) + ")(\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

I tried with and without the  Pattern.MULTILINE (I thought maybe it translated the dot as a NEW LINE...) and also tried to build it with  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE. 
It doesn't match...

Can you recognize what I'm doing wrong / advice how can I make it work?

Comment: flowers and FLOWERS is not really the same. not to Java, anyway. you can try first turning your original String to uppercases?

Comment: A suggestion.. Instead of using \\s to match whitespaces at the beginning / end, why don't you trim() the String and use a regex without \\s?

Comment: You must escape your dot (.) character. Otherwise, Java treats it as any character.

Comment: @gexicide He used `Pattern.quote(phraseToReplace)` to escape it

Comment: @DirkyJerky: Oh, right, only saw his first pattern and this one was wrong, didn't look at the java code :).

Comment: The representation for Quote are the \Q and \E - the regex (before the Java) is correct. Regarding the "FLOWERS" and "flowers" - it works fine with both. The only part it doesn't accept is the ".com" vs. ".COM" - it only works with ".COM". The (?i) is supposed to make sure that it will be case insensitive, isn't it...? (By the way, I'm a "she" and not "he" :-)  )

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)((?i)\\Q1-800 FLOWERS.COM, CO.\\E)(\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("1-800 flowers.com, CO.").find()` outputs `true`...

Comment: I used: `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phraseTOReplace.toUpperCase());    System.out.println(matcher.matches());`, and it returned true...

Comment: You are right! I'm too getting 'true' when running the find(). I'm using in my code the group() function - and this doesn't work...

Comment: Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)((?i)\\Q1-800 FLOWERS.COM, CO.\\E)(\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("1-800 flowers.com, CO.").group(2).

Comment: Your group 2 will be whatever "1-800" etc. text is matched in this case. You might have an issue if you're comparing it without ignoring case, to a desired `String` with different case.

Comment: Shouldn't the (?i) resolve this? What do you suggest to do?

Comment: No. The `(?i)` flag resolves the match. The group is actually what has been matched. Use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare `Strings` for equality by ignoring the case.

Comment: It's actually part of a sentence... I only simplified this for this example. I used regex instead of String.contains() to make sure it only finds whole words (the list of keys to find contains thousands of phrases).

Comment: Oops. Editing my answer then

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution to your issue, which seems to be about `String` equality ignoring case rather than case-insensitive matching.

To recap:

- `(?i)` or the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flags match case-insensitive
- The output of your groups is what has been matched, case won't be different from the text you're matching against
- To compare `String`s ignoring case, use `String.equalsIgnoreCase`
- To compare `String`s within `String`s ignoring case, use `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` on both terms (warning, can be expensive in terms of performance)

  ```
  String phraseToReplace = "1-800 flowers.com, CO.";

  String sentence = "blablabla " + phraseToReplace + " waddawaddawadda";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)((?i)" + Pattern.quote(phraseToReplace)
              + ")(\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher("1-800 flowers.COM, CO.");
  String match = null;
  if (m.matches()) {
      match = m.group(2);
  }
  if (match != null) {
      System.out.printf("Matched: \"%s\"%n", match);
      System.out.printf("Equals to \"phraseToReplace\"? %b%n", match.equals(phraseToReplace));
      System.out.printf("Equals to \"phraseToReplace\" ignoring case? %b%n",
              match.equalsIgnoreCase(phraseToReplace));
      System.out.printf("Contained in \"sentence\"? %b%n", sentence.contains(match));
      System.out.printf("Contained in \"sentence\" ignoring case? %b%n", sentence.toLowerCase().contains(match.toLowerCase()));
  }
  ```

**Output**

```
Matched: "1-800 flowers.COM, CO."
Equals to "phraseToReplace"? false
Equals to "phraseToReplace" ignoring case? true
Contained in "sentence"? false
Contained in "sentence" ignoring case? true
```

Comment: I ran the code - it is working. Continued to search why mine isn't and saw that the problem is that my sentence is being cut (because of another process between the client and server...). It actually being received as `phraseToReplace="1-800 flowers.com, "` (without the CO. and thus it doesn't match)... I'm going to solve it now... sorry for this mistake and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @CarmelBaumel-Ezra no probs.